# What do the question marks like ?: and ?! mean in Javascript regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

Like the regexp in this one? What does it match?

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = 
   document.getElementById("MyElement").className.replace
  ( /(?:^|\s)MyClass(?!\S)/ , '' )
```

Answer (score 4):

`?:` means make the capturing group a *non capturing group*, i.e. don't include its match as a back-reference. This is often done to increase performance and de-clutter the back-references when a capturing group is necessary to use the `|` operator.

In your example, it is being used to allow the *or* (`|`) of the start of the string `^` or whitespace (`\s`). Since the author of this code doesn't care about what it matched, they have made it a non capturing group.

`?!` is the negative lookahead. The regex will only match if the capturing group does not match.

In this example, the author wants to ensure the character after `MyClass` is *not* a whitespace character (`\S`).

It is somewhat possible the author of this code could have used word boundaries instead (`\b`).

Comment: Basically this RE means match *word* "MyClass" anywhere, not part of the word (don't match "MyClassExt" or "ThisIsMyClass" and e.g.)

Comment: What is the major difference between js regexp and regexps in other language like perl or php, I don't find the ?: and capturing group things on the tutorials provided by www.w3schools.com.

Comment: @trunpet: You should avoid w3schools as a resource. It's outdated and full of mistakes and bad advice.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression `(?:^|\s)` is a non-capturing group that matches either the start of the line or a whitespace character.

The regular expression `(?!\S)` is a negative lookahead assertion which succeeds either at the end of the string, or else when the next character is a whitespace character.